# Spring MVC Java Configuration session replication

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I'm working on porting over an application into Spring MVC using Java Configuration so I don't have to use a web.xml file anymore.

For the most part it is working, except for session replication.  The app currently runs on Tomcat and we use the distributable tag in the web.xml for session replication.

Does anyone know a way to make this work using Java configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Hazelcast for that. Please, see [How to configure Hazelcast for session caching using spring while limiting it to a set of nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868694/how-to-configure-hazelcast-for-session-caching-using-spring-while-limiting-it-to) for how to configure it.

Comment: Thanks, but from that link, it looks like I would need to configure it within my web.xml file.  I already can do that with Tomcat.  Was hoping to find a way to replicate sessions so I could do away with my web.xml completely.  Thanks again.

Comment: just create the filter programmatically com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter as you would do it. jhipster @ gihub does it.